# Can I pull python2 packages after support for python2 ends

Tags: python, boto3

I have a project written in python2. Suppose if I want to deploy my project after the end of life of python2 support, am I able to pull specific versions of specific packages?
For example, I am using boto3==1.4.7 version. So, am I able to pull the same version of the package after python2 support ends?

Answer (score 1):

That should be possible, but it is better to port your Project to Python 3 and use the newest versions of the packages.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider storing these packages on some local server in case the support goes down. For example, [boto3==1.4.7](https://pypi.org/project/boto3/1.4.7) is available as a tar.gz.